# PyCharm, Jupyter Kernel and Python console

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am giving a try to PyCharm professional for Python editing.  I created a project using the *"scientificProject"* template, which meets my needs (Or does it?).

I am using Conda to create the virtual environments.

Giving some background on why I want to do the following; for Clojure development I am able to evaluate chunks of code in `Emacs` into my *repl*, then play around with that code inside the *repl* as I please, edit my sources... evaluate again into my *repl*... which is amazing.

So far creating Jupyter notebooks works like a charm and I can work with them without much fuss (Installing the packages and so on).  However I would like to "plug" the Python console offered by Pycharm to the notebook kernel, so I can play around with the notebook's code.  Is this possible?  Which setup do you recommend?

So far I have been working with Jupyter's web application and `Emacs` for editing files.